# aligning text to input field inside a div in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, input, alignment

I am trying to align text to input fields. It works in chrome or FF but doesn’t in IE. any help appreciated. [Exemple](http://nagomedia.pl/media.html)

Comment: what version of IE? Works fine in IE8+ for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float:right` on the textboxes is unnecessary and it screws IE. Remove it (but keep the `text-align:right` on the parent `div`) and it displays fine in IE7+ (and Chrome)

Comment: @MichałKorzeniowski what version of IE do you have? It works for me.

Comment: @MichałKorzeniowski something's wrong with your IETester. Just tried 7,8, and 9 in my IETester and it worked fine. (Also tried in the _actual_ IE 7,8, and 9, and it worked fine too.